# Rails 'first' method running extra queries on Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am using Mongoid as the db for my Rails app.
Noticing too many QUERY lines in the log I decided to take a look.

Part of the code reads:

```
<%= if movie.directors.first
... Do something ...                  
end %>
```

For this the log showed two queries

```
 MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=tgmd-wiki collection=directors selector={"$query"=>{"$and"=>[{"_id"=>{"$in"=>["510a097b53c205c294000163"]}}]}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.7060ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=tgmd-wiki collection=directors selector={"$query"=>{"$and"=>[{"_id"=>{"$in"=>["510a097b53c205c294000163"]}}]}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.4706ms)
```

When I changed that to read:

```
<%= if movie.directors[0]
... Do something ...                  
end %>
```

there was only one query.

```
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=tgmd-wiki collection=directors selector={"$and"=>[{"_id"=>{"$in"=>["510a097b53c205c294000163"]}}]} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.7353ms)
```

Why is the **first** method doing a re-query at all?
Overlooking this as just a 0.4 ms difference isn't possible because
there are lot of such queries in my code.

Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but that .first would be mongoid related and not Rails itself.

As a side note it would probably be faster, or at least cleaner, to do

```
if movie.directors.any?
  ...
end
```

And of course eager load your directors so you don't even get that first query.

Comment: thanks for the eager loading technique. Didn't know of that. I am relatively new to rails.